# Eclipse plugins not showing up in project wizard

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I have installed all the plugins required for Android development and used them for a day - everything worked just fine. Today i run eclipse and there is no Android project in new project wizard or import project wizard. I didn't update eclipse or change anything.
I also tried installing Maven plugin. Everything ran as expected - it installed, requested for a eclipse restart and got the same problem. There is no new Maven project in the wizard.
Going Help -> Install new software shows the plugins as installed.
The eclipse is installed on ubuntu.

--Edit: Dont get the downvotes but ok. Just to be clear: The plugins showup nowhere in eclipse except on install new software tool and they are marked as installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone gets the same problem: I have reverted all the plugins, ran eclipse as admin, reinstalled plugins and everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

in eclipse go

`Proyect-> properties -> android`  look there if something is wrong

if there are an error add the appcompat (and delete the wrong path)

(your atd-bundle-Path/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat)

may be you need import the v7 in your workspace too

good luck